# JavaScript - NodeJS - HTTP - req.headers vs. req.getHeaders()

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, header, response

Why does this work:

```
const http = require('http');
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.write(JSON.stringify(req.headers)); // req.headers ✔️
  res.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

but this doesn't:

```
const http = require('http');
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.write(JSON.stringify(req.getHeaders())); // req.getHeaders() ❌
  res.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

..producing:

```
$ node script.js
<go to: http://localhost:3000/>
[...]
TypeError: req.getHeaders is not a function
```

..when the Node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/http.html#messageheaders) ([16.x doc is identical](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/http.html#messageheaders)), even under the section titled "*message.headers*", clearly demonstrates the use of:

```
console.log(request.getHeaders());
```

Comment: Neither in version v16 nor in v18 there is a `getHeaders()` method.

Comment: @Marc but why is it in the example in the documentations?

Comment: Good question. If i must guess, then perhaps from a draft or older example where some one thought it would be a good idea to have a method for returning the headers. If its not listed in the "table of contents" for "Class: http.IncomingMessage" then i would not try to use any methods from the examples/output. Other explanation would be that its a internal method. But that are just my 2 cents. The `getHeaders` method is listed under "ClientRequest" not for "IncomingMessages". Take a closer look at the Table of contents. Its a bit confusing.

Comment: Seems like the method does "just" not exists for IncomingMessages. They are exists for ClientRequests, OutgoingMessage & ServerResponse. But not for your http server which is a IngoingMessage.